# MySQL & webpage: Notification on insert in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have an application on a server that monitors a log file, I've also added a view at the client side (in the form of a website). Now I would like to implement the following: **Whenever a new entry has been added, the view should update as fast as possible.**

First I have thought of two practical solutions:

1) Call an AJAX function that requests a php page every second, which checks for updates, and if so show's them. (Disadvantages: Lots of HTTP overhead, a lot of the time there may be no message, lots of SQL calls)

2) Call an AJAX function that requests a different php page every minute, which also checks for updates for 1 minute, but only returns if it has found an update, or else after 1 minute. (Disadvantages: HTTP overhead, but less as option 1, may still have times without message, still a lot of SQL calls)

Which of those ones would be better, or what alternative would you advice?

I have also thought of yet another solution, but I'm unsure of how to implement it. That would be that on every `INSERT` on a specific table in the MySQL database, the webpage would directly be notified, perhaps via a push connection, but I'm also unsure of how those work.

Comment: Alternate is to use long-polling or web-sockets.

Comment: Use cron jobs to do so. The script should count the rows in the table. If there is an increase, then it should update your file

Comment: *as fast as possible* then option 1 otherwise option 2. Its like price v/s performance. Choose that suits you best

Comment: I believe a push method would even be faster as option 1, as that one could also respond in 500ms time intervals, in fact it could respond to any possible time interval. I'm having trouble on finding documentation on the push method though.